# Core Data - relationships or attributes?

Tags: core-data

I have a very basic, functioning, checklist application that I'd like to improve.

Essentially, it's just a list of 37,000 (and growing) items.

Right now, I have two entities:

[image: image of model]

1) Checklist: This includes the following attributes: name, numberOwned, imageName, groupName, etc - 14 in all. All are Strings

2) Keywords: This includes a single attribute: words, with a one-to-many nameKeywords relationship. This stores the normalized name for searching

My question is: Is there any reason to be using multiple entities in this type of situation? Should I remove the Keywords relationship and just add that as an additional attribute? Or should be be going the other route, minimizing the attributes and adding more entities?

I'd like to keep it as simple as possible (I'm not an experienced programmer, and the app isn't a source of revenue - it's available free on the store) - but I would like to make the searches more efficient if possible to make my users happy. Right now when a user searches for an item, it searches the normalized name in the Keyword entity, but it can take a while if they are trying to search through all items.

As usual, I apologize if this question is to vague. I'm happy to provide clarifications and code snippets as needed!

Zack

Comment: I'm not sure I followed the part about the `nameKeywords` relationship. It relates Keywords to Keywords? Is there any relationship between Checklist and Keywords?

Comment: @TomHarrington - I'm attaching a screenshot of the relationships and model  
![image of model](http://i40.tinypic.com/2chutd5.png)

Comment: Could you give an example of the strings that are actually stored in KEYWORDS for a particular CHECKLIST.  Would different CHECKLISTs ever have the same search keys words?  I am wondering whether your relationship should be many-to-many with each KEYWORD record containing a single word?  E.g. a search for "wibble" would return a single KEYWORD that has relationship to all CHECKLISTs that match this search.  This would make the search more efficient if the number of KEYWORDS is much less than the number of CHECKLISTS.  Whether this is the case or not will depend on your data.

Comment: @AndyEtheridge The nameKeywords are all the words from the normalized name, separated by spaces. So, for example, Marty McFly would get a normalized name of marty mcfly, and the keywords would be marty AND mcfly, that way when someone does a search for "ma" or "mc", marty mcfly would show up in the list.

Comment: If the keywords are common to multiple CHECKLISTs then use a many-to-many relationship. In this case there would only be a single KEYWORD entity with a property of "marty" and it would have a relationship to each CHECKLIST that has "marty" in the normalisedName.  This way you are searching a smaller number of entities.  If common keywords are rare then don't bother with the KEYWORDS entity, just use your normalisedName field.  You might want to include a space at the start and end of this field so that you can to startswith style searches by prepending a space to the search text.

Comment: @AndyEtheridge there are certainly common keywords, but not percentage wise (ie, there are probably 500 figures with the keyword spider-man, but out of 38,000 items, it's a pretty small percentage). Is the suggestion then to eliminate the second entity all together and just make the keywords part of the checklist entity? or is there an advantage to searching a keywords entity?

Answer (score 0):

To increase the speed of search, you can use indexes for attributes, but it'll help if you can show your model of database

Comment: I've updated the question with a link to an image of the database model - thanks!